# php://input - what does it do in fopen()?

Tags: php, fopen

```
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.gif", "wb");
```

I can understand this that `/home/rasmus/file.txt` and `/home/rasmus/file.gif` are the file path.

But what these mean:

```
php://input
php://temp
```

in

```
$objInputStream = fopen("php://input", "r");
$objTempStream = fopen("php://temp", "w+b");
```

What do they do?

Comment: See [PHP input/output streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating `always_populate_raw_post_data`. php://input is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Check out the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: The last sentence is no longer accurate.  Setting [`enable_post_data_reading = 0`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) will disable the parsing of the `php://input` stream into `$_FILES`, making `php://input` readable for multipart requests.

Answer (score 6):

`php://temp` stores data in a temporary file which is only accessible for the duration of the script's execution.  It is a real file, but is cleaned up as soon as the script terminates unlike a true file opened with `fopen()`, that will persist on the filesystem.

`php://input` is used for reading the raw HTTP request body, without having the `$_POST` and `$_SERVER` variables abstracted out.  The `php://input` stream would give access to the entire HTTP request as the server handed it to the PHP interpreter.

Comment: Not entirely true: *"php://temp will use a temporary file once the amount of data stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB)."*

Answer (score 3):

Those are [stream wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and allow you to read from various streams. The reading and writting to stream is performed in the same way as with the file (some limitation can exists, for example not every stream wrapper supports fseek).
`php://input` gives you access to the raw HTTP data (it's available in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA if server is configured to prepopulate it). Best - read the corresponding section in the documentation

Comment: ...so what do the modifier flags do?