# What is the meaning of php://input & php://output and when it needs to use?

Tags: php

What is the meaning of `php://input` & `php://output` and when it needs to use?
Please explain with an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php://input - what does it do in fopen()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083702/php-input-what-does-it-do-in-fopen)

Answer (score 39):

These are two of the [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) that PHP provides. Streams can be used by functions like [fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [fwrite](http://www.php.net/fwrite), [stream_get_contents](http://www.php.net/stream_get_contents), etc.

`php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read the request body sent to it (like uploaded files or POST variables).

```
$request_body = stream_get_contents('php://input');
```

`php://output` is a writable stream that is sent to the server and will be returned to the browser that requested your page.

```
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Hello World!'); //User will see Hello World!
fclose($fp);
```

Note that if you are in the CLI, php://output will write data to the command line.

Comment: Why should one need `php://output`? Isn't it the same as using 'echo'?

Comment: It's the same as using "echo", _except_ it lets you use all the function you'd normally use for sending out put to a file.  Sometimes, that will let you do what you want more directly or more readably.

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) has a good explanation and examples.

If you have trouble understanding something that is said there, feel free to ask again specifically - the more detailed the question, the better it is usually received.