# PHP : how to retrieve piped stuff

Tags: php

Not a dupe, in this very case I am trying to run my php thru a command line and it does not work as expected (php uses php://input and I do not want to modify them)

I am trying the following:

```
echo 'hello' | php -r 'print("input content:".file_get_contents("php://input"));'
```

I am expecting something like

```
content:hello
```

to be printed out , but get only

> content:

Comment: Do you execute it in the CLI ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of php://input & php://output and when it needs to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186189/what-is-the-meaning-of-php-input-php-output-and-when-it-needs-to-use)

Comment: is there any reason why you want to get the input as php://input ?

Comment: Yes this is executed in a CLI , I have many php with file_get_contents("php://input")

Comment: @user3665736 You can still use `file_get_contents`, just use `stdin` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 5):

Please try with `stdin` instead:

```
echo "hello" | php -r 'print_r("input content:".file_get_contents("php://stdin"));'
```

More about CLI streams: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact I have many php scripts using file_get_contents("php://input") and I try to figure out how to pass the info in command line

Comment: php://input is for request body, in command line you'll have standard input: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: Yes I want to simulate a request body (some JSON string in fact)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// loop through each element in the $argv array
foreach($argv as $value){
  echo "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact php://input will only work if I use php-cgi instead of php
So to pass a request body code is like:

> echo '{"a":1}' | php-cgi -r 'print("input
>   content:".file_get_contents("php://input"));'