# PSR-7: getParsedBody() vs getBody()

Tags: php, json, post, http-post, psr-7

**Scenario 1** sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` data

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar
```

Running `print_r($request->getParsedBody());` returns fine:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)
```

Running `print_r($request->getBody()->getContents());` returns a string `foo=bar`

---

**Scenario 2** sending `application/json` data

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Running `print_r($request->getParsedBody());` returns an empty array. `Array ( )`

But, running `print_r($request->getBody()->getContents());` returns fine:

`{"foo":"bar"}`

---

Is this expected behavior?

Meaning, if we're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, we should use `getParsedBody()`.

While `getBody()->getContents()` should be used if we're sending  `application/json`?

---

**Additional info:**

Request object is created using:

```
$request = \Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals(
        $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_FILES
);
```

Comment: 1) Which PSR-7 library are you using - maybe zend diactoros? 2) To each scenario, you should provide the code for building the _ServerRequest_ object. 3) To "Scenario 1": Have you also tried activating the `StreamInterface::__toString` method with something like this: `$content = (string) ($request->getBody()); echo $content;`? I'm asking this because a `StreamInterface::__toString` method implementation _"MUST attempt to seek to the beginning of the stream before reading data"_, whereas `StreamInterface::getContents` only _"Returns the **remaining** contents in a string"_.

Comment: @dakis Actually scenario 1 seems to actually return a string `foo=bar` when using `$request->getBody()->getContents()`. I've update the scenarios. Also included how request object is created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Message body:**

In a PSR-7 library, the *message body* is abstracted by the `StreamInterface`. Any implementation of this interface MUST wrap a [PHP stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) and, of course, should provide the proper functionality to perform the specific read/write/seek operations on it. PHP provides a list of I/O [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), from which `php://input` is suitable for the task in question.

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. `php://input` is not available with *enctype="multipart/form-data"*.

In this context, when a request to the server is performed, the request body data (regardless of its data type) is automatically written to the `php://input` stream, in raw format (string). The information can later be read from it by calling `StreamInterface::getContents`, `StreamInterface::__toString`, or `StreamInterface::read` (which would probably make use of `stream_get_contents()`, or similar, in their implementation).

***Note:*** The method `StreamInterface::__toString` is automatically called when the object representing the message body, e.g. the instance of the class implementing `StreamInterface` is cast to a string. For example, like this - see [Type Casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) in PHP:

```
$messageBodyObject = $request->getBody(); // implements StreamInterface
$contentOfMessageBody = (string) $messageBodyObject; // cast to string => StreamInterface::__toString is called

echo $contentOfMessageBody;
```

**Parsed body:**

In regard of the PSR-7, the *parsed body* is a "characteristic" of the applications where PHP is *"used as a server-side application to fulfill HTTP requests"* (in comparison with the applications where PHP is used as *"an HTTP client"*) - see [Summary of the PSR-7 Meta Document](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/meta/#1-summary). So, the *parsed body* is a component of the `ServerRequestInterface` only.

The *parsed body* (read the comments of `ServerRequestInterface::getParsedBody` and `ServerRequestInterface::withParsedBody`) is thought as a representation in a "parsed" form (array, or object) of the raw data (a string) saved in the `php://input` stream as the result of performing a request. For example, the [$_POST variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.post-description), which is an array, holds the *parsed body* of a POST request, under the conditions presented bellow.

**Relevant use-cases:**

If a POST request is performed and the header `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (for example when submitting a normal HTML form), the content of the request body is automatically saved into both the `php://input` stream (serialized) and the $_POST variable (array). So, in the PSR-7 context, calling both `StreamInterface::getContents` (or `StreamInterface::__toString`, or `StreamInterface::read`) and `ServerRequestInterface::getParsedBody` will return "valid" values.

If a POST request is performed and the header `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data` (for example when performing a file(s) upload), the content of the request body is NOT saved into the `php://input` stream at all, but only into the $_POST variable (array). So, in the PSR-7 context, only calling `ServerRequestInterface::getParsedBody` will return a "valid" value.

If a POST request is performed and the header `Content-Type` has other value than the two presented above (for example `application/json`, or `text/plain; charset=utf-8`), the content of the request body is saved only into the `php://input` stream. So, in the PSR-7 context, only calling `StreamInterface::getContents` (or `StreamInterface::__toString`, or `StreamInterface::read`) will return a "valid" value.

**Resources:**

- [PSR-7: HTTP message interfaces](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/)
- [PSR-7 Meta Document](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/meta/)
- [How to get body of a POST in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945912)
- [PHP "php://input" vs $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792)
- [php://input - what does it do in fopen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083735) (the comment to the answer)

Comment: (string) $request->getBody(); // returns raw json payload, as long as $request is implementing ServerRequestInterface

Comment: @pofqggg Hi. Thanks. But could you please be more precise in what you are trying to tell me/us?

Comment: just summarizing what you wrote on the topic. To get the raw payload from a request object, implementing ServerRequestInterface - (string) $request->getBody(); is the way

Comment: @pofqggg Nice suggestion. Thank you again. I completed my answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @dakis is correct, but I find it a bit ambiguous in answering the original question of why Scenario 2 failed.

From a PSR standpoint, the behaviour is correct (as @dakis said):

- body returns a stream to the request body
- parsedBody is a characteristic of the request and  *can* contain a parsed representation of the body (*but is not required to*), as mentioned in the PHPDoc of `ServerRequestInterface::getParsedBody`:

  > Otherwise, this method may return any results of deserializing the request body content; ...

From a usefulness perspective, laminas-diactoros is lacking and, in my opinion, half-baked. This library doesn't seem to do a lot more than passing around data already parsed by PHP (`$_GET`/`$_POST`..). A better implementation would have handled the specific content-type for use with parsedBody and would have automatically thrown or handled bad POST data.