# Capture incoming request data

Tags: php, routes, request, thephpleague

I have been experimenting with the current version of the wonderful package for [routing](https://route.thephpleague.com/) from [thephpleague](https://thephpleague.com/).

I have a simple index page to handle the routing and it works just fine.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory;
use Laminas\HttpHandlerRunner\Emitter\SapiEmitter;
use Laminas\Diactoros\ResponseFactory;
use League\Route\Router;
use League\Route\Strategy\JsonStrategy;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

$strategy = new JsonStrategy(new ResponseFactory());
$router = new Router;
$router->setStrategy($strategy);

$router->post(
    '/hello',
    function (ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
    {
        var_dump($request->getParsedBody());
    }
);

$request = ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals(
    $_SERVER,
    $_GET,
    $_POST,
    $_COOKIE,
    $_FILES
);
$response = $router->dispatch($request);

// send the response to the browser
(new SapiEmitter)->emit($response);
```

My problem is when I send a `POST` request with `JSON` data in it, I am unable to capture it in my code as indicated by the line `var_dump($request->getParsedBody());`.

At the moment, the only way I am able to capture the data sent with the request is by running `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`.

What I do need to do in order to get the payload sent with whatever request, be it `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, or otherwise?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you send your POST request with the appropriate Content-Type header, so the server _knows_ it is supposed to be JSON?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I am using [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/products/insomnia) to send my requests.

Comment: What actual implementation of `ServerRequestInterface` is this using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. After close examination, I think using [dependency injection](https://phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection),  `ServerRequestInterface` is mapped to `Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequest`.

So, to illustrate

```php
$router->post(
    '/hello',
    function (ServerRequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface {
        var_dump(
            $request->getHeaders(),
            $request->getParsedBody(),
            $request->getQueryParams(),
            $request->getUploadedFiles(),
            $request->getBody()->getContents(),
            $request // Laminas\Diactoros\ServerRequest
        );
    }
);
```

where

1. `$request->getHeaders()` gives you the request headers
2. `$request->getParsedBody()` will return to all the data as an array sent through when the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` is set (at least as far as I have experimented)
3. `$request->getQueryParams()` gives all the query string params as an array just like `$_GET`
4. `$request->getUploadedFiles()` gives all the the uploaded files as an array of instances of `Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile`
5. `$request->getBody()->getContents()` will return to all data the as a string when the header `Content-Type: application/json` is set. You can then run `json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true)` to get the actual contents an array

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer fits your question, but the reason is that laminas/diactoros does not fully handle requests with a JSON body. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73671455/314056