# PATCH Request Body empty after converting Symfony HttpFoundation to PSR7

Tags: symfony, guzzle, psr-7

I'm attempting to send a PATCH request as follows, convert it to PSR7 and then validate the request using OpenAPI PSR-7 Message (HTTP Request/Response) Validator, which fails with the following message, "Schema(or data) validation failed: All of the required rules must pass for `{ }`".

I suspect its the request itself, or how I'm using the Symfony PSR bridge.

```
curl -X PATCH "http://local.domain/api/v1/path/a60360dc-a32e-49a1-bf03-20bf8c2bbbdf" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"property":"value"}'
```

And converting the HttpFoundation to PSR7 as follows:

```
$psr17Factory = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\HttpFactory();
$psrHttpFactory = new \Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\PsrHttpFactory($psr17Factory, $psr17Factory, $psr17Factory, $psr17Factory);
/** @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request */
$psrRequest = $psrHttpFactory->createRequest($request);
```

When debugging, the request $body from PsrHttpFactory::createRequest() [here](https://github.com/symfony/psr-http-message-bridge/blob/v2.2.0/Factory/PsrHttpFactory.php#L70) (note the 2.2.0 version), appears as seen in the attached screenshot.

[image]

However, after the conversion, I get the following.
$psrRequest->getParsedBody() is an empty array.
$psrRequest->getBody()->getContents() is an empty string.

Comment: Have you tried a different PSR7 implementation? `$psrRequest->getBody()->getContents()` is likely coming back empty because the stream has already been read and it won't rewind it by itself. Check the output of `$psrRequest->getBody()->__toString()` instead.

Comment: @AndrewGillis - `$psrRequest->getBody()->__toString()` returns the expected `{"property":"value"}` object.

By "different PSR7 implementation", do you mean a package like nyholm/psr7? I tried using its Psr17Factory() with the same results.

Comment: Right so that is the expected behaviour for PSR-7. Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101751/psr-7-getparsedbody-vs-getbody) for more info.